# Javascript Table with Arrays and Loops - Broken

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, html-table

Broken table using an 1 & 2 Dimensional Arrays with for-loops.

**How can I get "loanAmount[row] to display only one time on the left most column of the table?**

```
  function print2DArrayTable(this2DArray, title)
   {
   //Creates the header of the table
   document.write("<table border='1' cellpadding='5'>");
   document.write("<tr><th colspan='8'>");
   document.write("<h2>" + title + "</h2>");
   document.write("</th></tr>")


      //Creates the Year headers on top of the table columns.
      document.write("<th></th>");
      for(x=0; x<numberOfYear.length; x++)
      {
         document.write("<th>" +numberOfYear[x]+ "</th>");
      }


      for(row=0; row<this2DArray.length; row++)
      {  
         document.write("<tr>");
         for(col=0; col<this2DArray[0].length; col++)
         {
            document.write("<td>"+loanAmount[row]+"</td>");
            document.write("<td>");
            document.write(this2DArray[row][col] + "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            document.write("</td>");
         }
         document.write("</tr>");

      }
      document.write("</table>");
   }/* end of print2DArraytable */
```

The first column is correct. but every other one is not..
Here is a picture of it. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your line that generates the first column outside of your inner loop.

```
for(row=0; row<this2DArray.length; row++)
  {  
     document.write("<tr>");

     // We only want to do this once per row
     document.write("<td>"+loanAmount[row]+"</td>");

     // After writing out the first column, write out the rest
     for(col=0; col<this2DArray[0].length; col++)
     {

        document.write("<td>");
        document.write(this2DArray[row][col] + "&nbsp;&nbsp;");
        document.write("</td>");
     }
     document.write("</tr>");

  }
```